# Insert data to specific table, but got an error in another table in Lumen 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, lumen-5.8

Trying to insert data to `books` table, but got an error in `users` table. Here is the error

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `id` is null limit 1)

Migration table

```php
Schema::create('books',function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id_book');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->string('slug');
    $table->string('author');
    $table->string('isbn')->unique()->notNullable();;
    $table->text('summary');
    $table->integer('stocks');
});
```

Model `Books.php`:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Books extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'books';
    protected $fillable = ['title','slug','author','isbn','summary', 'stocks'];
    protected $dates = [];

    public static $rules = [
        'title'   => 'required',
        'slug'    => 'required',
        'author'  => 'required',
        'isbn'    => 'required',
        'summary' => 'required',
        'stocks'  => 'required'
    ];
}
```

`store` function in `BooksController.php`

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    Books::create($request->all());
    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Successful create new product'
    ]);
}
```

For information, there's no `id` column in `users` table.

I also tried query builder in `store` function, but it returns same error. How can I solve it? Thank you.

Comment: Change id_book to id

Comment: @Digvijay I think it's not variable naming error

Comment: i cant see how the code you pasted calls `users` table anywhere, so the issue must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

inside your Model Books.php, add this

protected $primaryKey = 'id_book';

this overrides the default primary key from id to id_book for the Books model, repeat the same for any other table in corresponding model file.

hope it helps